# How to extract comments from Object literals in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I'm trying to extract comments from different javascript objects. In the case of a function, I can easily do it by using .toString and then apply a regex to the function output. However, If the object is an object literal with comments I can't extract the comments because of course toString returns `[object Object]` I've tried use `Object.toSource` but that seems to strip out the comments :/. I'm wondering if there is any smart hack to do this.

I release I could wrap the object literal in a function and then call `.toString` but I don't have access to the where it is defined - I am just passed the reference.

For clarity:

```
const myFunction = () => {
  // I can extract this
  return 'foo'
}

const myObject = {
  // I can't extract this
  foo: 'bar'
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need this?! ...

Comment: `myObject` is not an object?! Type it in devtools console, it output `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @hobochild No way...

Comment: @ManUtopiK  - sorry thats a typo - i've updated the code snippet.

Comment: @JonasWilms, I'm building a [little utility](https://github.com/hobochild/js-fire) to automatically create cli's from functions and objects - this would be used to get the description for the command. I realize I could just have some special `__description__` key on object for this but I'd like to have no API other than standard javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible at runtime. You should use file parser or something like jsDoc will be better.